# Bank account model implementation in Django

Tags: python, finance, django

There is a draft of my models.py. What can I do for code quality and readability increase?

```
from datetime import timedelta

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Rule(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

    deposit_percent = models.FloatField()
    credit_percent = models.FloatField()

    @staticmethod
    def on_date(_date):
        return Rule.objects.get(start_date__lte=_date, end_date__gte=_date)


class BankAccount(models.Model):

    LEGAL = 1
    NATURAL = 2

    DEBET = 1
    CREDIT = 2

    owner_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=(
        (LEGAL, 'Физическое лицо'),
        (NATURAL, 'Юридическое лицо'),
    ))

    method = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=(
        (DEBET, 'Дебет'),
        (CREDIT, 'Кредит'),
    ))

    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='w_accounts')
    spectators = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='r_accounts')
    when_opened = models.DateField()

    @property
    def balance(self):
        assert self.method == self.DEBET
        today = timezone.now()
        rule = Rule.on_date(self.when_opened)
        result = 0
        current_date = self.when_opened
        while current_date <= today:
            result -= sum(x.total for x in self.cashing_set.on_date(current_date))
            result -= sum(x.total for x in self.outcome_transfers.on_date(current_date))
            result += sum(x.total for x in self.deposit_set.on_date(current_date))
            result += sum(x.total for x in self.income_transfers.on_date(current_date))
            result *= 1 + rule.deposit_percent * 0.01
            current_date += timedelta(days=1)
        return result

    @property
    def debt(self):
        assert self.method == self.CREDIT
        today = timezone.now()
        rule = Rule.on_date(self.when_opened)
        result = 0
        current_date = self.when_opened
        while current_date <= today:
            result += sum(x.total for x in self.cashing_set.on_date(current_date))
            result += sum(x.total for x in self.outcome_transfers.on_date(current_date))
            result -= sum(x.total for x in self.deposit_set.on_date(current_date))
            result -= sum(x.total for x in self.income_transfers.on_date(current_date))
            result *= 1 + rule.credit_percent
            current_date += timedelta(days=1)
        return result


class OperationManager(models.Manager):

    def on_date(self, date):
        return (super(OperationManager, self).get_queryset()).filter(when__gte=date, when__lte=date)


class MoneyTransfer(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(BankAccount, related_name='outcome_transfers')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(BankAccount, related_name='income_transfers')
    when = models.DateTimeField()
    total = models.FloatField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    objects = OperationManager()


class Deposit(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(BankAccount)
    total = models.FloatField()
    banker = models.ForeignKey(User)
    when = models.DateTimeField()

    objects = OperationManager()


class Cashing(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(BankAccount)
    total = models.FloatField()
    banker = models.ForeignKey(User)
    when = models.DateTimeField()

    objects = OperationManager()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general this seems fine, easy to read, you seem to be following [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), that's excellent.

At first look, this repeated logic in `balance` and `debt` jumps in the eye:

> ```
> @property
> def balance(self):
>     # ...
>     while current_date <= today:
>         result -= sum(x.total for x in self.cashing_set.on_date(current_date))
>         result -= sum(x.total for x in self.outcome_transfers.on_date(current_date))
>         result += sum(x.total for x in self.deposit_set.on_date(current_date))
>         result += sum(x.total for x in self.income_transfers.on_date(current_date))
>         # ...
>
> @property
> def debt(self):
>     # ...
>     while current_date <= today:
>         result += sum(x.total for x in self.cashing_set.on_date(current_date))
>         result += sum(x.total for x in self.outcome_transfers.on_date(current_date))
>         result -= sum(x.total for x in self.deposit_set.on_date(current_date))
>         result -= sum(x.total for x in self.income_transfers.on_date(current_date))
>         # ...
> ```

My immediate reaction is to extract those summations to a helper method, for example:

```
def sum_total_transfers(self):
    result = 0
    result -= sum(x.total for x in self.cashing_set.on_date(current_date))
    result -= sum(x.total for x in self.outcome_transfers.on_date(current_date))
    result += sum(x.total for x in self.deposit_set.on_date(current_date))
    result += sum(x.total for x in self.income_transfers.on_date(current_date))
    return result
```

So that the above methods can reuse that with less duplication:

```
@property
def balance(self):
    # ...
    while current_date <= today:
        result += self.sum_total_transfers()
        # ...

@property
def debt(self):
    # ...
    while current_date <= today:
        result -= self.sum_total_transfers()
        # ...
```

On closer look, these assert lines don't look good:

> ```
> @property
> def balance(self):
>     assert self.method == self.DEBET
>     # ...
>
> @property
> def debt(self):
>     assert self.method == self.CREDIT
>     # ...
> ```

These assertions force the callers to check the value of `self.method` before using these properties,
or to organize the code in a way that ensures that `.debt` will only be called when `self.method == self.CREDIT`, otherwise the program would crash.
It would be better to avoid such unwritten rules.

For example, it might be better to have one public property that applies the correct calculation based on the method:

```
@property
def balance(self):
    if self.method == self.DEBET:
        return self._credit_balance
    return self._debt_balance

@property
def _credit_balance(self):
    assert self.method == self.DEBET
    # ...

@property
def _debt_balance(self):
    assert self.method == self.CREDIT
    # ...
```

Lastly, "debt" is misspelled in `self.DEBET`.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into custom querysets in Django for your `Rule.on_date` static method.

> ```
> @staticmethod
> def on_date(_date):
>     return Rule.objects.get(start_date__lte=_date, end_date__gte=_date)
> ```

This appears to get all rules that are in effect on a certain date (docstrings *might* be useful, that's a guess), which is likely a common query that needs to be done. Usually helper methods for queries, such as this one, would go on the manager instance, allowing it to be called like

```
 Rule.objects.on_date(some_date)
```

Instead of putting it as a static method on the model. You can see examples of this in [the User manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#manager-methods). This can be accomplished by either making a custom [`Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/) or a custom [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/), and associating it with your model. I personally typically [make the `QuerySet` work as the `Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#creating-manager-with-queryset-methods), so I can use it anywhere within a query.

```
from django.db import models

class RuleQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def on_date(_date):
        return self.get(start_date__lte=_date, end_date__gte=_date)

class Rule(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

    deposit_percent = models.FloatField()
    credit_percent = models.FloatField()

    objects = RuleQuerySet.as_manager()
```

You are actually doing something similar to this further down, in your `OperationManager`, but you are extending from a `Manager` there instead of a `QuerySet`. If it's possible for there to be multiple rules for a day, you might also want to consider switching `self.get` to `self.filter`.

Comment: thank you! It's so helpful! Unfortunately, I have no enough reputation for voting up...